# Using Ansible, how can I convert a string to an integer to pass as the uid parameter to the user builtin?

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible to set up a docker container. One task is to create a copy of the user running the ansible script. My YML is this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get username
      become: false
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: id -nru
      register: result
      when: docker_user is undefined
    - set_fact:
        docker_user: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      when: docker_user is undefined

    - name: Get userid
      become: false
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: id -ru
      register: result
      when: docker_uid is undefined
    - debug: var=result.stdout
    - set_fact:
        docker_uid: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      when: docker_uid is undefined
    - debug: var=docker_uid

    - name: create a docker user
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: docker_user
        uid: docker_uid
        home: '/home/{{docker_user}}'
      when: ansible_connection == 'docker'
```

When I run it I get the error: `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument 'uid' is of type <type 'str'> and we were unable to convert to int: <type 'str'> cannot be converted to an int"}`

I tried changing the "uid" line to: `uid: docker_uid | int` but that didn't help.
The debug line reports that docker_uid is "1000". How do I pass this value as an integer to the user uid parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run the commands. Ansible [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) provides you with the variables

- ansible_user_id
- ansible_user_uid

1. Use them

```yaml
    - block:

        - setup:
            gather_subset: user
        - set_fact:
            docker_user: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
          when: docker_user is undefined
        - set_fact:
            docker_uid: "{{ ansible_user_uid }}"
          when: docker_uid is undefined

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      when: docker_user is undefined or
            docker_uid is undefined
```

gives (if docker_* are undefined) for example,

```yaml
  msg: |-
    docker_user: admin
    docker_uid: 1000
    docker_uid|typ_debug: int
```

2. Make the code more robust. 'Instantiate' (set_fact) *docker_user* also when defined and get the ID from *passwd*

```yaml
    - block:

        - setup:
            gather_subset: user
        - set_fact:
            docker_user: "{{ docker_user|d(ansible_user_id) }}"
        - getent:
            database: passwd
        - set_fact:
            docker_uid: "{{ getent_passwd[docker_user].2 }}"

      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives (if docker_* are undefined) for example,

```yaml
  msg: |-
    docker_user: vlado
    docker_uid: 1000
    docker_uid|typ_debug: AnsibleUnsafeText
```

In this case, the type of *docker_uid* is a string because [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) was used to evaluate the expression. The type of a Jinja result
is always a string. Jinja is a template designer.

```yaml
  docker_uid: "{{ getent_passwd[docker_user].2 }}"
```

The type of *docker_uid* in the previous expression is integer because Jinja wasn't needed to evaluate the expression. It's a plain assignment and the type of *ansible_user_uid* is an integer

```yaml
  docker_uid: "{{ ansible_user_uid }}"
```

3. The situation complicates further if you assign the variable *docker_uid* on the command line. In the first case

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e docker_uid=1000

  ...

  msg: |-
    docker_user: admin
    docker_uid: 1000
    docker_uid|typ_debug: str
```

the type of *docker_uid* is a string because the INI format "docker_uid=1000" always converts to a string

If you use the YAML format the type can be an integer

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "{docker_uid: 1000}"

    ...

    docker_user: admin
    docker_uid: 1000
    docker_uid|typ_debug: int
```

**Conclusion**

Always convert the variable to the integer when the integer is needed

```yaml
    - name: create a docker user
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ docker_user }}"
        uid: "{{ docker_uid|int }}"
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

docker_user and docker_uid are variables. Check how to use variables

here you used a variable > home: '/home/{{docker_user}}'